# Java hashmap building <String, Integer>

Tags: java

I am trying to enhance the code on a JAVA project.

an old method was to build a hashmap manually like this - essentially taking parameters from a form a batch of String numbers --

So ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings -- would be like "22"

```
Map<String, Integer> sDMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
         sDMap.put("ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings", BasicUtils.strToIntConversion(ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings));
         sDMap.put("RestlessOveractiveCannotStayStillForLong", BasicUtils.strToIntConversion(RestlessOveractiveCannotStayStillForLong));
```

so the map would populate ideally like this

```
OLD MAP.........{StealsFromHomeSchoolOrElsewhere=2, HasAtLeastOneGoodFriend=0}
```

-- I am trying to create this same map - with a hashMapBuilder function

```
public static Map<String, Integer> hashMapBuilder (String[] array){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for( String element : array ) {
        map.put(element.toString(), BasicUtils.strToIntConversion(element));
    }
    return map;
}
```

although the response is not correct.

```
NEW MAP.........{0=0, 1=1, 2=2}
```

---

the strToIntConversion looks like this - as it will take a null/string value and convert it into an Integer

```
public static Integer strToIntConversion(String str){
    int number = 0;
    try {
        if(str != null){
          number = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        number = 0;
    }
    return number;
}
```

---

when I do this it returns {0=0, 1=1, 2=2} --

```
String[] myStrings = {ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings, RestlessOveractiveCannotStayStillForLong, OftenComplainsOfHeadachesStomachachesOrSickness};
        Map<String, Integer> newMap = BasicUtils.hashMapBuilder(myStrings);     
        System.out.println("NEW MAP........."+ newMap);
```

Comment: Your `array` should be containing `String` representation of Numbers like `0,1,2,3,4` . That is the reason , your key is string value of `0` or `1 `or `2` but your values are int` 0 or 1 or 2`. If you had `"ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings"` in your `array`, you would have that as key in your new` hashmap`, but the value would be `0` because of `NumberFormatException` in your utility. You need to get those string keys like `"ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings"` from somewhere to use in your new `hashmap`.

Comment: Is there anything like variable.nameOfVariable etc..

Comment: Since you are only giving the `hashMapBuilder()` method the *values* from the named variables, not the name of the variables, where did you expect the method to get the names? If the named variables are *constants*, i.e. static fields of a particular class, you could give the `hashMapBuilder()` method the names as strings, and have the method use reflection to get the values.

Comment: No, there is nothing like `variable.nameOfVariable`.

Comment: - yeah so kind of what Jimmy just said - but is there something like wrapping the variable in a string like " + variable + " --

Comment: You can create a new class that holds variable name in string, and its value in int . When you populate that array, populate with the object of this class . So basically while adding number to your array elements, you will also be adding it to your string name. Now you have name and value preserved in your array of your objects.

Comment: -- Cheers Jimmy - like what corsiKa just provided -- the thing is you see - I got a hashMap of these .puts for nearly 20-30 fields -- and thought there must be a cleaner way of doing this - or making hasmaps like this generally

Answer (score 0):

In the old code you have:

`sDMap.put("ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings", BasicUtils.strToIntConversion(ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings));`

This is a string: `"ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings"`
And this is a variable probably holding the numerical valu: `ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings`

so you should be using those variables as well

Comment: @AVC - just updated my question - I am doing that -- I put the values in a String[] array -- but instead of taking the name of the variable -- it converts its actual value into a "string number"

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use annotations to make this happen

```
class MyData {

    @RobSearchable String ConsiderateOfOtherPeoplesFeelings;
    @RobSearchable String RestlessOveractiveCannotStayStillForLong;
    @RobSearchable String StealsFromHomeSchoolOrElsewhere;

}
```

Later, you could do this

```
public static Map<String, Integer> hashMapBuilder(MyData data){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(Field f : data.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(f.getAnnotation(RobSearchable.class) != null) {
            String element = f.get(data).toString();
            map.put(element.toString(), BasicUtils.strToIntConversion(element));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Now, as you continue to add fields to your data, they will all automatically show up in the map, as long as you annotate them properly.

Comment: Nice trick, but it's bad because uses reflection. But depends on the application

Comment: Using reflection doesn't make it bad. Reflection is a *good* thing. Say it with me. Reflection is a *good* thing.

Comment: :) is a good thing for libraries and utilities, not for code that contains business logic, that has to be read and debugged over and over again.

Comment: And why do you say that? What about business logic makes it bad?